# JQuery Ajax format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Javascript coding, I have the following javascript funtion.

```
function submitRegistrationForm(){

            var fname = $('#fname').val();
            var lname = $('#lname').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            var region = $('#from').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'registration.php',
                data:'FrmSubmit=1&fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&region='+region,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg == 'ok'){
                        $('#fname').val('');
                        $('#lname').val('');
                        $('#email').val('');
                        $('#phone').val('');
                        $('#region').val('');
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Thanks for registering on Graphics BootCamp Class, we\'ll contact you soon for more updates.</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                    }
                    $('#submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            });
        }
```

But it always prints an error message "Some problem occurred, please try again."
what could be the reason? I would appreciate for assistance please.

More edits

Here is my registration.php file, I have tried several ways but still the same problem.

```
//Database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "graphics";

$connection = @mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
    if($connection){
        $db = @mysql_select_db($database,$connection);
        if(!$db)
            die("There was an error, try again later");     
    }else
        die("There was an error, please try again later");


if(isset($_POST['FrmSubmit']) && !empty($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['phone'])&& !empty($_POST['from'])){

    // Creating variables
    $fname   = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname   = $_POST['lname'];
    $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $region = $_POST['from'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO graphics_class VALUES(NULL,"'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'","'.$phone.'","'.$email.'","'.$region.'")";

    // submitting to database
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
        $msg = 'ok';
    }else{
        $msg = 'err';
    }

    // Output message
    echo $msg;die;
}
```

Comment: what is being returned from your `registration.php` file as ajax response...?

Comment: If `msg` is anything other than "ok" your error message will display. So what is the actual value of `msg`? Monitor the request using your browsers developer tools.

Comment: what is the value of `msg` on success ?

Comment: I need to send those person information to registration.php file to be submitted to the database

Comment: I don't know the value of msg on success, I just found that function online and edited to meet my requirement, I hope that is a built in function, msg should have a value of ok on success!

Comment: `[...]I don't know the value of msg on success[...]` then log that message or print it along with the `Some problem occurred`. How should we be able to guess what is wrong. Or log the error in the `registration.php` in a file.

Comment: You need to check msg value. You can try simple tricks as add debug point in success callback function and verify using browser developer tools. Other simple thing you can just log msg value on console by adding statement say, console.log(msg).

Comment: "I hope that is a built in function, msg should have a value of ok on success!" `msg` is whatever you echo from your PHP. So if you didn't tell it to say "ok" then it won't. You can run `alert(msg);` in your Javascript to check its value easily. If you need some more help, you might want to show us your PHP

Comment: P.S. This `data:'FrmSubmit=1&fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&region='+region,` is very prone to errors because you're not URL-encoding the variables, so anything with special characters in it which mean something in a URL e.g. & or # or  % might cause your request to go wrong because the server doesn't understand the querystring. The easiest way is just to make a JS object from all of those and let jQuery handle the encoding for you.

Comment: Another unrelated but useful point, unless you are using jQuery 1.5 or less you should be using .prop() instead of .attr() to set the "disabled" property of elements. This is clearly documented both here http://api.jquery.com/prop/ and here http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Thank you @ADyson and @Nitin, I have tested `alert(msg)` then it gives the expected result `ok` but it contains the html codes of `registration.php` file, what could be the problem with my code?

Comment: Ooh! Finally Solved, there was an undefined index in my `registration.php` file which was resulting the output of error, I had to read line after a line of that output `msg` to realize the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is on registration.php file, there is undefined variable on line

```
$region = $_POST['from'];
```

the `from` index does not match the one specified in Ajax code on line

```
data:'FrmSubmit=1&fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&region='+region,
```

I had to replace the `from` index with `region`, then it worked fine.

The issues was that, PHP identified an undefined index and output an error to the Ajax call then nothing worked since JavaScript does not give error notification, therefore it was difficult to recognize.